# Is it Safe to Change the Name of a .desktop File in /usr/share/applications?

Tags: gnome, .desktop, mime-type

I use Lubuntu (18.04) and several Gnome apps. By default Gnome apps are given generic association names like 'Terminal' for gnome-terminal and 'text editor' for gedit, which is confusing considering there are dozens if not more of each type of app to choose from in the repos. When I select an app to open a file with I want to see the actual name of the app.

Today I figured out that I can do so by renaming the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, and I have tried it with gedit so far and haven't noticed any issues yet. I want to know if there might be any undesirable consequences that I don't know of before I start renaming other files. The only thing I can think of myself is that if I update an app the name might revert to its default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically 'safe' to modify files in `/usr/share/applications`, but files under `/usr` (with the exception of those under `/usr/local`), should be left under the control of system management commands, such as `apt install`.

The clean solution is to copy the desktop file (for instance `gedit.desktop` or `gnome-terminal.desktop`) to either `/usr/local/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`, and make your desired changes in the resulting file.

Desktop files put in `/usr/local/share/applications` override those in `/usr/share/applications` and are system-wide.  Files in `~/.local/share/applications` in turn override the system-wide file for a single user.

Comment: Hello, sorry for such a delayed response. Could you please explain what you mean by "technically safe"? Do you have any examples of something going wrong after modifying files under /usr/?

Comment: 1. Modified files under `/usr` will be overwritten when the package is reinstalled or upgraded. 2. New files created under `/usr` (and their directory) will not be cleaned up when the package that "owns" the directory is removed. 3. A file created under `/usr` will break installation of a package with a file with the same name.